# Pg_restore table size differences

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, ubuntu, restore

What would account for the difference in table sizes between one PostgreSQL database and another restored from its dump file?

On an Ubuntu 12.04 host, I'm running PostgreSQL 9.1, and I dumped my database using:

```
pg_dump -c -U myuser --blobs --format=c mydb -n public > mydb.dump
```

Prior to the dump, with autovacuum enabled, the table `mytable` was listed in `pg_tables` as being 31GB in size and has 21961903 rows.

I loaded this dump file onto a separate Ubuntu 12.04 host, using:

```
pg_restore --jobs=8 -U postgres --create --dbname=mydb mydb.dump
```

It loaded mostly fine, only reporting one error creating an index because of an "unexpected end of data" on table `mytable`, which it says it ignored. However, pg_table reports that the size of `mytable` is only 7.7GB but still has 21961903 rows.

Why the disparity in table size measurements? Should I be concerned with the error creating the index on my table?